# Does the proof of Yamabe problem gives a method for finding metric of constant scalar curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Yamabe problem states that:

> Given a smooth, compact manifold $M$ of dimension $n \geq 3$ with a Riemannian metric $g$, does there exist a metric $h$ conformal to $g$ for which the scalar curvature of $h$ is constant?

The answer is now known to be yes and I want to know

> **Question:** Does the proof of Yamabe problem give a method for finding metric of constant scalar curvature? If the answer is positive, then what is its method?

Thanks.